# My @Transactional is malfunctioning in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch

I'm having trouble with making a save in my Spring Batch project.

Here's my service method that I'm using in my writer:

```java
public void saveMember(List<? extends MemberResult> list) {
   for (MemberResult memberResult : list) {
      try {
         saveMemberItem(memberResult);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error("An error has occurred while saving the member");
      }
   }
}
```

And this is my "saveMemberItem" method:

```java
 @Transactional
public void saveMemberItem(MemberResult memberResult) {
   if (Objects.nonNull(memberResult)) {
      memberResultRepository.save(memberResult);
   }
}
```

This isn't the complete method, as there are more things I need to add.

I'm using JPA to save the records and I'm trying to save many records, with the first one having existing information in the database and the second one having new information.

When I try to save the first record, I get a database error about a constraint conflict, which is expected.

But when the process tries to save the second record, I get the same constraint error as the previous one. I evaluate the "save" method again, and now the saving is okay. But when I run the Spring Batch process without debug, I get the error I mentioned before.

I'm using the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation in my `Application.java` class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the two methods defined in the same class? IIRC, transactional only works for calls across different Spring beans.

Comment: @daniu I was going to ask the same question.  The way Spring proxies methods requires calls to be external calls (if you want the annotation to work).  See https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring which says "Any self-invocation calls will not start any transaction, even if the method has the `@Transactional` annotation."

Comment: Also, after over a decade of using Spring Framework, Spring Security, and various other Spring projects, I'm confident in saying that when someone thinks Spring is broken there's a 99% chance that person is wrong. :)  Sure, Spring has bugs but encountering one in a basic, core feature is highly unlikely.

Comment: question: why is the transaction management here relevant? As you described it, you are saving X entities and the first one is expected to throw, but the second one is not, but somehow the second one throws too. Are you expecting that the first save is getting rolled back? Because if the constraint happened, then you dont need to rollback since it wasnt inserted anyway, so this means for me that the second entry in the list is faulty aswell

Comment: @daniu that's right. I was defining both methods in the same class, I tried to change it and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Victor Glad to hear your issue is solved! It would be great to share your solution in an answer and accept it, so that other people having the same issue know how you did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in comments, there are some caveats in how Spring handles transactions. And if that's the case and you do have these two methods in the same class - it won't work properly. You could go around with something like this:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Lookup
    public MyService self() {
       return null;
    }

}
```

And then call saveMemberItem like this `self().saveMemberItem (...)`.

P.S. I'm not sure how good is this way of retrieving self, but there are other ways which you can find on the Internet.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-self-injection

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different guess of what could cause the error:

You mentioned that you use spring batch and spring batch has a Transaction per chunk **already**.

Given the following code:

```
@Transaction
public void foo(Object obj){
    repository.save(obj);
}
```

What happens behind the scenes is that the code gets proxied to something like this:

```
public void foo(Object obj){
    try {
        repository.save(obj);
    } catch(Exception e){
        markForRollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

you are catching the exception one level higher:

```
public void abc(){
    try {
        foo(obj); //here the first save throws, goes throug the proxied code, gets rethrown and is caught here
    } catch(Exception e){
        log.error("error!");
    }
}
```

But this means that the markForRollback() is getting executed! Since you already have a transaction because of spring batch, the whole batch is **likely** getting rolled back (but not sure here! thats why its a guess) at the end of the chunk.

You can try 3 things:

- move the try catch code into the saveMemberItems method
- remove the @Transactional annotation, because then the proxy is not markign the whole transaction for rollback
- You can change the annotation to: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW), which means a new transaction is getting created and you **only** rollback the first save and nothing more

I would go for the second solution